# PHP file as soft DB?

Tags: php

I want to use a PHP include file for a soft DB of about 20 elements. The actual data will be collected from RRD files and thus I prefer not to use MySQL just for 20 elements. The file fruits.php for the elements I'm trying something like:

```
<?php
$fruit="Apple"; $colour="red";
$fruit="Banana"; $colour="yellow";
$fruit="Pear"; $colour="green";
?>
```

In my recall file, results.php, I currenlty have the following code to recall the information from the fruits.php file:

```
<?php
include 'fruits.php';
$num=count($fruit);
$i = 0;
while ($i < $num){
echo "<p>My ".$fruit." is ".$colour.".</p>";
$i++;
}
?>
```

Since I'm not a proper scriptor/programmer, I'm quite blind to what should be different and stupid to proper coding. I have tried some other methods as well, one included:

```
$num=glob($fruit);
```

Any assistance with this will be really appreciated. Just to confirm the output I'd like for this code is to be:

```
My Apple is red.
My Banana is yellow.
My Pear is green.
```

Comment: Look up **arrays** in php http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: consider using serialization instead of storing your array as a PHP file. Especially if data in fruits.php gets changed by your application.

Comment: @Dagon the solution below worked great but I will still follow your link which will be good for my knowledge, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case, variable $fruit will have a value  "pear", and $colour = "green"
Because you always redefine it

```
 <?php
 $fruits = array();
 $fruits[] = ["name" => "Apple", "colour"=>"red"];
 $fruits[] = ["name" => "Banana", "colour"=>"yellow"];
 $fruits[] = ["name" => "Pear", "colour"=>"green"];
 ?>
```

1st way:

```
<?php
include 'fruits.php';
$num=count($fruits);
$i = 0;
while ($i < $num){
echo "<p>My ".$fruits[$i]["name"]." is ".$fruits[$i]["colour"].".</p>";
$i++;
}
?>
```

2nd way ([much easier](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)):

```
<?php 
include 'fruits.php';
foreach ($fruits as $fruit){
  echo "<p>My ".$fruit["name"]." is ".$fruit["colour"].".</p>";
}

?>
```

where $fruit is element of the array $fruits

Comment: the 2nd easier way worked perfect in my actual pages. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Your fruits.php file should probably contain an associative array, like:

```
<?php
    $fruits = Array(
        Array( 'fruit' => 'Apple', 'color' => 'red' ),
        Array( 'fruit' => 'Banana', 'color' => 'yellow' ),
        // etc...
    );
?>
```

Then you'd access it in your code like

```
<?php
    echo "<p>My ".$fruits[$i]['fruit']." is ".$fruits[$i]['color'].".</p>";
?>
```